# parse inner xml data

Tags: android

How can I get value of **name** in below xml format?

Here is my code.

> `<Tracking>   <ImageTarget size="140 292" name="teapot"/>   </Tracking>`

Comment: Include the code you've tried.

Comment: [Let me do it for you?](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=android+xml+parsing+get+attribute+value&oq=android+xml+parsing+get+attribute+value&gs_l=hp.3..33i29.21438.23791.2.24126.12.12.0.0.0.3.227.2226.0j10j2.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.Ey3hxJoQYxU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=27efcd70b7deef07&biw=1280&bih=921)